# How to set the Tab Visibility in android?

Tags: android, tabs

I am having a tab widget with three tabs, I need to set the visibility for that when the:

```
tabhost.setcurrentTab(0);
```

the other two tabs should be invisible.

Comment: It is better to provide xml and some java code  to understand ur problem

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: ok i will edit my question with code.

Comment: Also specify what do you mean by "invisible". Do you want the tab's upper selector widget to dissapear (looking like it's a single tab tabhost), or the content of the tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `visibility` to `View.GONE` for the tab you want to hide, as follows:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(hiddenTabPosition)
                      .setVisibility(View.GONE);
```